# A classe Firebase não está sendo encontrada para importação

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Fiz todo processo abaixo:

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'

    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0"// banco
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0' // autenticador 
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0' //arquivos

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // esse


buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' // esse

    }
}
```

Parece está tudo correto, porém não estou conseguindo declarar um objeto Firebase.

Ex: `Firebase novoObjeto;`

A classe `Firebase`não está sendo importada.

Quando começo a digitar `Firebase`, aparece `Firebaseapp`... e assim por diante... não aparece somente `Firebase` para eu poder declarar!

Comment: Me parece que a classe `Firebase` não existe. Segundo a [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) a classe para trabalhar com o banco é `FirebaseDatabase`. Chegou a ver em algum tutorial/documentação essa classe `Firebase`?

Comment: Estava assistindo o tutorial abaixo: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sL4PhbN5ws&feature=youtu.be

e no minuto (4:25) o palestrante declara o objeto firebase. Se puder assistir e conseguir me auxiliar, ficarei eternamento grato.

Comment: Então, esse vídeo é muito antigo, que usa a versão antiga do Firebase. Recomendo fortemente que veja a documentação atual, em português: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/?hl=pt-br